# Creating a function within a class which has an integer value

Tags: python, class, self

Getting a "this code will never be reached" under self.weight, for some reason. The code all works, however the self.weight inst returned when i print this function

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,weight):
        self.name=name
        self.weight=weight

    def BMI(self):
        return self.name
        return self.weight


person1=Person("john",52)
print(person1.BMI())
```

Comment: Why do you have `return self.name` at all? What output were you expecting?

Comment: just testing classes out for the first time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions can only return one value and terminate upon the first encountered return statement. For that reason, calling `BMI()` returns the name and

```
return self.weight.
```

statement isn't reached.

Comment: thanks, is that just for functions within  a class or just functions in general

Comment: All functions can only return one value.  that said, the value can be a tuple (an ordered pair/triplet/etc), so there are ways around that restriction

Comment: so if within the BMI function, I wanted to return the name john and his weight of 52, how would I do this, because return(self.name+self.weight) wont work

Comment: @mob all functions. Really there is no difference if your function is within a class or not *except one thing*, which is when that function is accessed as an attribute of an instance of that class, the first argument is passed the instance itself. This is why the first argument is conventionally named `self`, but note, it is simply a function for all other purposes.